# Infinite loop in procedure genexus

Tags: procedure, genexus

I have one table called `Categoria` that have **CategoriaId** primary key and `CategoriaPaiId` foreign-key with auto-relationship with `CategoriaId`.

I need to create a procedure that returns a tree of categories.

Supossing that i have this categories with this subcategories:

**Perishable > Drinks > Wine > Red**

In register Drinks, i need that the variable  &CategoriaSubCategoriaNome returns this varchar:

**Perishable> Drinks.**

In register Red, i need that return in the variable &CategoriaSubCategoriaNome the string:

Perishable> Drinks> Wines

This is the procedure that i have created:

```
&isTrue = true
&isAchou = true
do while &isTrue = true
    if &isAchou = true
            &isAchou = false    
            for each
                where CategoriaId = &CategoriaPaiId
                &CategoriaSubCategoriaNome = &CategoriaSubCategoriaNome+ " > " + CategoriaNome
                &isAchou = true
            endfor
        if &isAchou = false
            return
        endif
    endif
enddo
```

But i'm getting a infinite loop in this procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of the structure of your transactions. For this answer I show you how to get the category name hierarchy using a formula:

**Transaction Category:**

```
CategoryId*
CategoryName
CategoryFullName  formula: GetCategoryFullName(CategoryId)
CategoryParentId  <nullable=Yes>
CategoryParentName
```

**Subtype Group CategoryParentGroup**

```
CategoryParentId* sbt CategoryId
CategoryParentName sbt CategoryName
```

**Procedure GetCategoryFullName**

in Rules: `parm(in: CategoryId, out: &CategoryFullName)`

in Source:

```
for each
    &CategoryFullName = iif(CategoryParentId.IsNull(), 
                            CategoryName, 
                            GetCategoryFullName(CategoryParentId) + !' > ' + CategoryName)
endfor
```

Comment: Changed my code to ours, but my developer menu doesn't open when i run the project and when i access this api i'm getting only loading... i think i'm still in loop :(

Comment: @VeroneseComS: Are you sure you have put CategoryParentId as Nullable=yes ?. Have you tried to do a rebuild all ? Its also important that procedure GetCategoryFullName to have attribute `CategoryId` as an input parm

Comment: yes, CategoryParentId is nullable. And the proccedure i defined the parm as: parm(CategoryId, out: &CategoryFullName);

Comment: @VeroneseComS: To pinpoint the problem you may comment out the source from the procedure as it's the only place where recursion is performed

Comment: what is the funcionallity of the ! after the CategoryParentId parameter?

Comment: @VeroneseComS: the `!` **before** a string literal indicates that the literal should not be considered for translation

Answer (score 0):

I would resolve it recurrently:

Proc: CategoryList

Rules:

```
Parm(in:&CategoriaId, out:&CategoriaStr);
```

Source:

```
for each Categoria
where CategoriaId = &CategoriaId
if CategoriaPaiId.IsEmpty()
    &CategoriaStr = CategoriaNome
else
    &CategoriaStr = CategoryList(CategoriaPaiId) + !" > " + CategoriaNome
endif
when none
    &CategoriaStr.SetEmpty()
endfor
```